# Truncate line numbers when they are too large

Tags: line-numbers, margin

So I'm using Vim's line numbering with

```
set number
set numberwidth=4
```

But I find that if line numbers exceed 999, then the gutter is automatically expanded to accommodate them.   I actually don't want this--I use vim within tmux and need to preserve pane size as well as the number of columns in the editor.  I would rather have the most significant digit(s) cropped, so that line 1234 appears as 234, for example.  Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without a custom scripted solution (and even that I'm not 100% sure about). There's a setting for the minimum width but not the maximum. As far as a partial solution, it's hard to imagine Vim having a builtin setting that allows something ugly like truncating the numbers.

Comment: This is not possible

Comment: please paste picture here, so the problem will become more directly.